# Publish .aar to Jitpack using Kotlin Gradle without sources.jar

Tags: android, kotlin, maven, gradle

I am trying to publish Adnroid library `.aar` to Jipack using `maven-publish` without **sources.jar** from kotlin gradle kts.

**AGP**: 8.2.2

**Kotlin**: 1.9.22

**Gradle**: 8.2

**Java**: 17

**Android Studio**: Hedgehog

Below is the library module `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.util.archivesName

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("maven-publish")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mylibrary"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        version = "2.0"
        archivesName = "myLib"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("release") {
            groupId = "com.example.mylibrary"
            artifactId = project.archivesName.get()
            version = project.version.toString()
            pom.packaging = "aar"
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/myLib-release.aar")
            afterEvaluate {
                from(components["release"])
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}
```

Jitpack produced artifacts reference:

**Files:**

```
com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC-bcf5c2b-sources.jar

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC-bcf5c2b.aar

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC-bcf5c2b.module

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC-bcf5c2b.pom

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC-bcf5c2b.pom.md5

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC-bcf5c2b.pom.sha1

com/github/amirraza/Jitpack-Artifact-PoC/bcf5c2b/build.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after spending much time on the internet to find the best possible answer. I finally got the solution. What you have to do is to `disable` the gradle task that runs to generate sources.

Module level `build.gradle.kts`:

```
/**
 * Configures the publishing of the Android library to a Maven repository, 
 * targeting JitPack. This script defines a Maven publication named "release"
 * and configures artifact publication and dependency management.
 */
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            register<MavenPublication>("release") {
                from(components["release"])
                //groupId = "com.example.myapp"
                artifactId = "HelloLib"
                version = "1.0.0"
            }
        }
        repositories {
            // Configure JitPack repository
            maven {
                url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
                credentials {
                    username = gradleProperties.getProperty("authToken")?.toString() ?: ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Disables the execution of specific tasks of type AbstractArchiveTask.
 * It iterates over all tasks of this type and checks if their names are
 * either "releaseSourcesJar" or "debugSourcesJar". If a task has one of these names,
 * its enabled property is set to false, effectively preventing it from executing.
 */
tasks.withType<AbstractArchiveTask> {
    if(this.name == "releaseSourcesJar" || this.name == "debugSourcesJar") {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```